# Sudden Change in Out-Of-The-Box SharePoint Online News Webpart Appearance

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm experiencing inconsistent behavior in the SharePoint Online out-of-the-box ("OOTB") News webpart. To illustrate the problem, I'll be comparing the experience between two completely unrelated tenants, which I'll refer to as A and B. The News webpart behavior on Tenant A has changed in the last couple days, but I'm not experiencing the problem on Tenant B.

One of the content managers for Tenant A brought to my attention a recent, sudden change in the way News item thumbnails appear. Before a few days ago, thumbnails would scale to fill the entire tile. This would cut off some of the image, but this was expected and acceptable. However, thumbnails recently started sizing themselves to fit entirely inside the tile, leaving large, empty spaces underneath. See below for an example, and note the dark blue empty space underneath the tile on the left:

[image]

This behavior is consistent across many other types of sites with modern pages in Tenant A. As I mentioned, this is the OOTB web part.

The experience on Tenant B is different. Images scale exactly as they should. See below:

[image]

The image in the left-hand tile scales to fill the entire space, cutting off some of the photo. This is how we want Tenant A to behave and how it has behaved until recently.

Through my investigation, I've discovered a small structural change between these two OOTB News webparts:

[image]

Note that the misbehaving tenant, Tenant A, wraps the thumbnail image in a div with "display" and "justify-content" styles applied. There is no such div wrapper in Tenant B, which behaves as expected. When I overwrite the style in the dev tools and change the "display" property to "inline," the thumbnail image expands to fill the tile, which is what I want.

My question is: Does anybody know why these two OOTB News webparts seem to have different structures? Does anybody know whether some configuration or customization of a base template that I'm not aware of may have led to this? Is there a recent Microsoft update that may be to blame (that just hasn't hit Tenant B yet)? Any insight is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are both tenants on same release level? either [targeted release or standard release](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365)??

Comment: Second part of this is, because it is an OOTB webpart, there's nothing we can do to help you -- it is better to open a case via admin.microsoft.com.

Comment: All Standard release. I should also mention that Tenant A is Enterprise and Tenant B is personal.

Comment: Can the standard display templates for OOTB web parts be altered at the tenant level?